# Permalinks of archive tag wordpress

Tags: permalinks, tags, archives

I try to add link of tag archive in text that contain tag.

For example:- if i have tag that name "football" and in single.php i display the content like "the_content();", So now when article have word like " football " it must be add link to get me all article have word " football ".

I do this function, but i need the the link of tag archive ???

```
function tag_content_replace($post_content) {
   global $wp_query, $post;

   if (!is_single() ) return $post_content;
  $content_with_tags_link = $post_content;

 $posttags = get_the_tags();
 if ($posttags) {
   foreach($posttags as $tag) {
   $tag_name = ' '.$tag->name.' ';
  $link_ = ' <a href="'.get_permalink(get_the_ID()).'" title="'.$tag->name.'">'.$tag->name.'</a> ';
  $content_with_tags_link =  str_replace($tag_name , $link_ ,$content_with_tags_link)  ; 

  }
}


$content_with_tags_link = preg_replace('/<img.*src="(.*?)".*\/>/', '<a href="'.get_permalink(get_the_ID()).'" title="'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'"><img src="\1" alt="'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'" title="'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'" /></a>', $content_with_tags_link);


 return  $content_with_tags_link;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to create the tag-archive page link is to ask it to WordPress with:

```
echo get_tag_link($tag_id_or_tag_object)
```

the function is smart enough to deal with id(s) or full tag objects like the ones returned by get_the_tags().

See here for more about the tag link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link